# UIPopoverViewController over selected text (see attached pic)

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiwebview, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to place a UIPopoverController in my iPad app next to the highlighted text in my UIWebView.

sort of like this: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/infoyle.png/

I think I have to implement the

```
 [QL_Popover presentPopoverFromRect:? inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
```

Comment: It's an instance of uipopupcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you do have to implement that.

Comment: That was a confusing sentence. Took me a while. But you'll have to build something for it (honestly, I don't know what). But if you wanted a solid answer from someone about that, maybe you should put that question in the actual question itself (currently, your question only asks if you should implement that; which you should)..

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a pop over? Maybe you can use a tooltip like this http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html